# Pivot table 0 totals displayed as non-zero in scientific notation

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I have this pivot table showing the ones with "0" total as ***E-15***.

[image]

Not sure if it's my code or Excel itself?

But even when I do it manually its giving me scientific notation.

However my goal is to get the ones with sum = 0 and delete them from the master table.

Should I use something other than a pivot table?

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
  "ACCL!R1C1:R1048576C50", Version:=7).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
  newSheet.Name & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=7
Sheets(newSheet.Name).Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
    .DisplayErrorString = False
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .EnableDrilldown = True
    .ErrorString = ""
    .MergeLabels = False
    .NullString = ""
    .PageFieldOrder = 2
    .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RowGrand = True
    .SaveData = True
    .PrintTitles = False
    .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
    .TotalsAnnotation = False
    .CompactRowIndent = 1
    .InGridDropZones = False
    .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
    .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
    .DisplayContextTooltips = True
    .ShowDrillIndicators = True
    .PrintDrillIndicators = False
    .AllowMultipleFilters = False
    .SortUsingCustomLists = True
    .FieldListSortAscending = False
    .ShowValuesRow = False
    .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
    .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Doc Number")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
  "PivotTable2").PivotFields("LT 1 Amount"), "Sum of LT 1 Amount", xlSum
Columns("A:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
  :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Rows("1:2").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A1").Select
    
Sheets("Dubs po 0 inv total").Select
Sheets("Dubs po 0 inv total").Name = "0 inv total"
Sheets(newSheet.Name).Select
Sheets(newSheet.Name).Name = "0 DOC total"

Sheets("0 DOC total").Move Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("ACCL").Select

Sheets("ACCL").Select
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should `round` all your raw data to `two decimal point` after `divided`, else when the decimal is more than 3, it will display as `xxE-15` as per your image.

Comment: it's already rounded up to 2 decimal places

Comment: Try format your pivot table total and see, if rounding was not done for all data, then you might see `0`, `0.00`, `(0.00)`, although all of them should be 0 only..

Answer (score 0):

so i ended up rounding it in the code itself instead or rounding in the sheet, used the round function and it worked just fine!

rnd = Round(.Value, 2)

```
                If rnd <> "0" Or rnd = "" Then .EntireRow.Delete
```